# Spring MVC Errors are not shown to user

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn spring MVC. I have a User Registration form which has some validations to be applied. I have written a controller for it and used javax validation annotations on the model class i.e. UserBo.

I have used Spring MVC  tag to show any errors found by @Valid annotation. However, the errors are not visible on screen.

Following are the files in my setup.
The Model: UserBO

```
package com.shailesh.beans;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class UserBO {

    public enum MaritalStatus {
            SINGLE, MARRIED
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "UserBO [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName
                            + ", id=" + id + ", phone=" + phone + ", maritalStatus="
                            + maritalStatus + "]";
    }

    @NotNull(message="First Name can not be null")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String phone;

    @NotNull
    private MaritalStatus maritalStatus;

    public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Long getId() {
            return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
            return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
            this.phone = phone;
    }
    public MaritalStatus getMaritalStatus() {
            return maritalStatus;
    }
    public void setMaritalStatus(MaritalStatus maritalStatus) {
            this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    }
```

}

---

The Controller : AllPathController

```
package com.shailesh.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.shailesh.beans.UserBO;

@Controller
public class AllPathController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String register(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("userBo", new UserBO());
            return "registerform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("userBo") UserBO userBo, BindingResult result, Model model) {

            if(result.hasErrors()) {
                    System.out.println("Input has some errors :"+result.toString());
                    //model.addAttribute("userBo", userBo);
                    return "registerform";
            }

            System.out.println("Input user details :" +userBo);
            return "helloboss";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/homepage", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String show() {
            return "homepage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/helloboss.do", method=RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String show2() {
            System.out.println("get");
            return "helloboss";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/helloboss.do", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String show3() {
            System.out.println("post");
            return "hellobosspost";
    }
}
```

---

The Spring context.xml file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans         
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd ">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.shailesh.controller.*" /> -->

    <bean id="allPathController" class="com.shailesh.controller.AllPathController" />

    <bean id="resolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
            <property name="basename" value="views" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

---

And the very own registerform.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
    <sf:form method="POST" commandName="userBo">
    First Name :     <sf:input path="firstName" />
        <br />
        <sf:errors path="firstName" element="div"/>
    Last Name :     <sf:input path="lastName" />
        <br />
        <sf:errors path="lastName" />
    Phone :     <sf:input path="phone" />
        <br />
        <sf:errors path="phone" />
    Marital Status : 
        <sf:select path="maritalStatus">
            <sf:options path="maritalStatus" />
        </sf:select>
        <sf:errors path="maritalStatus" />

        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My observation is, when i give path value for  as "*", it works. However, when i use some specific value ex. firstName , it doesn't show any errors. I tried debugging in this case. I can see the errors being populated inside BindingResult but not shown on UI.

Any help is appeciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it works for all fields when you specify "*" path? I'm just wondering about NotNull validation. It probably will be empty string when submit form and from my understanding should be annotated as NotEmpty

Comment: Yo... Adding @notempty annotation makes it work. But I still wonder why the bindingresult on inspection inside eclipse shows me that it found some errors but not shown on ui. Thanks for the inputs.